# What is the difference between a vocative and an epithet?

Tags: vocatives

I've seen them used in almost similar circumstances, and I'm not sure what the difference is.

The **victim** cried out in despair.

He was a real **idiot**.

Are those vocatives, epithets, or neither?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My dictionary defines ***epithet*** as follows:

*n. an adjective or phrase expressing a quality or attribute regarded as characteristic of the person or thing mentioned: old men are often unfairly awarded the epithet 'dirty'.*

So I don't see how either of your examples qualifies as an *epithet*.

***Vocative*** *denotes a case of nouns, pronouns, and adjectives in Latin and other languages, used in addressing or invoking a person or thing.*

Perhaps the most famous vocative of all time were the words Shakespeare attributed to Caesar as he was stabbed by the conspirators *Et tu Brute* (Even thou, O Brutus) - *Brute* being the vocative of *Brutus*.

**Hence I do not think either of your examples qualify either as epithets or vocatives.**

Comment: *Look out* is either an imperative sentence, or an interjection, not a vocative, as it does not specify who should be doing the looking out - the very purpose and diagnostic feature of a vocative. *Oh my toe* is probably a misinterpretation of *Ow, my toe!*, an ejaculation - unless you are actually talking to your toe and expecting it to listen. English vocatives are not grammatically marked, but *John* in *John, could you come here?* is a vocative, as is *you* in *Hey, you!* (and certainly Caesar's *Brutus* in *O Brutus*). That said, I agree that the OP contains no vocatives whatsoever.

Comment: @Amadan Thank you for that contribution. You are quite right and I have edited accordingly. It is over half a century now, since I studied Latin!