# Metaphorical reference to a specific person/place

Tags: metaphors, figures-of-speech

Is there a grammatical term that describes the use of a figurative reference in place of directly naming a specific person, place or thing? Terms such as metaphor, metonym, etc. apply to classes (eg. "crown" for a king/queen), but I'm thinking of phrases that uniquely identify a particular person, place, etc.

Examples:

- The "patient log-man" refers to Ferdinand in The Tempest.
- The "baffled king composing Hallelujah" refers to King David.
- The "city of seven hills" refers to Rome.

I've explored the standard tropes such as metaphor, metonym, synecdoche, metalepsis and so on, but none seems to quite fit the bill since each can apply to an entire class of referent ("boots on the ground" for soldiers generally). I've also explored terms such as pseudonym et. al. but these tend to describe the substitution of one *name* for another, rather than the use of a *phrase* in place of a name.

As well as identifying the correct grammatical term, I'd be interested in hearing any other examples that people can suggest. Any help greatly appreciated.

Edit 1: Suggestions so far include "epithet", "soubriquet" and the (possibly neologistic?) phrase "nominative idiom". I'll keep digging...

Edit 2: The best suggestion so far is "epithet", but this (a) only applies to people (AFAICS) and (b) can be joined to more than one person (Peter the Great, Alexander the Great, etc). It's hard to imagine "the bard of Avon" applying to more than a single, very specific person, and this is the distinction I'm trying to make.

Comment: Does these answer your question? [A less derogatory alternative for "epithet"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/570388/a-less-derogatory-alternative-for-epithet) // [What is the difference between a vocative and an epithet?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/207639/what-is-the-difference-between-a-vocative-and-an-epithet)

Comment: Epithet still seems like it would apply to classes rather than individuals, but it led me in turn to soubriquet which I'd overlooked and I think is getting closer to what I'm trying to express, so thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Where are you getting this distinction between "applying to classes rather than individuals"? Metaphors apply to everything. It's generics that create classes, not metaphors.

Comment: Before describing King David as the "baffled king composing Hallelujah," Cohen already names David in his lyrics. Looks like a descriptor to me. Same with describing Rome with a nickname, along with Big Apple, Big Easy, City by the Bay, City of Lights, and Paris of the Middle East.

Comment: Hi John, the distinction between classes and individuals is the essence of my question, since I seek a term that applies *only* to metaphors whose referent is a unique object, in the same way that "as blind as a bat" is a metaphor but is also, more specifically, an example of hyperbole.

Comment: Hi Yosef, I agree these examples are descriptors, but I'm looking for a more specific term, not a more general one. I seek a term that applies *only* to metaphors where the referent can be uniquely identified.